# Proof involving division algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to prove the following.

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers, $n>m$. Prove that if $n$ divided by $m$ leaves
>    remainder $r$, then $2^n - 1$ divided by $2^m-1$ leaves
>    remainder $2^r-1$.

So I wrote:

$$
n = mq_1 + r \Rightarrow 2^n-1 = (2^m-1)q_2 + r'
$$

I was trying to manipulate the sentence on the right to get $r'=2^r-1$. Is this a good path? Then I substituted $n$ for $mq_1+r$, since that's the hypothesis. Like this:

$$
r' = 2^{mq_1+r} -1 - q_2(2^m-1)
$$
$$
r'= 2^{mq_1}2^r - 1 - q_2(2^m - 1)
$$
$$
r'=(2^m)^{q_1}2^r - 1 - q_2(2^m - 1)
$$

Anyway, that didn't help much. At some point I'll have to deal with $q_1$ and $q_2$, but I don't know how. I noticed that, since $r$ is the remainder, $n \gt m \gt r$. But is that useful?

Can you please help me? I'm having a hard time in my undergraduate classes of Algebra. I know all the properties but I can't seem to use them to get somewhere, i.e., I usually can't use them to prove anything. The teacher is already talking about prime numbers, but I'm still struggling to understand the first lessons on division algorithm and divisibility.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\rm\ \  a^n\!-\!1\ =\ a^{n-m} \: (a^m\!-\!1) + a^{n-m}\!-\!1.\ $ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7561/23500) for much more.